# Python C Extension Need to Py_INCREF a Borrowed Reference if not returning it to Python Land?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

If you obtain a borrowed reference but do NOT return it to Python land, should you be doing a `Py_INCREF` when you obtain it and then a `Py_DECREF` once you are done with it, or is this superfluous?

For example, this trivial example gets a borrowed reference from `PyDict_GetItem`, does some stuff with the borrowed reference, and then returns `None` to Python land. Is there any need to `Py_INCREF`/`Py_DECREF` the borrowed reference while working with it here?

```
static PyObject PyFoo_bar(PyFoo *self, int field)
{
    int field = 0;

    PyFoo *child = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &field) {
         return NULL;
    }

    child = PyDict_GetItem(self->children, field);

    // Long code omitted that works on child
    // Is it safe to do so without a Py_INCREF on child now followed by PY_DECREF later?

    // NOT returning child here - just return None
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

My worry here is that after calling `PyDict_GetItem`, the reference count of `child` can somehow drop to zero and then deallocate while I am working with it. Is that even possible? I don't think so, since the GIL isn't dropped here, but I am not sure.

On the other hand, I wonder if it's just best practice to do a `Py_INCREF`/`Py_DECREF` here. Maybe later on I drop the GIL, or later decide to return the child. `Py_INCREF` is cheap. For example, would it be better to do it this way:

```
child = PyDict_GetItem(self->children, field);
Py_INCREF(child);
// Long code omitted
Py_DECREF(child);
Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the intermediate "long code" does. If it executes Python code that you have no control over, then it's perfectly possible that that code accesses the `self->children` dict and deletes `field`, at which point yes, its refcount can drop to zero. So you'd want to protect against that case and add INCREF/DECREF.

Note that any use of `child` will require reading the type object pointer, which sits adjacent to the reference count and the latter will thus have been loaded on the same cache line. With out-of-order execution, the INCREF/DECREF are basically free operations, so performance is no reason to leave them out.

The best reason I can think of for *not* doing INCREF, is when the "long code" has multiple exit points (but does not execute arbitrary python code or touch `self->children` as explained above). You'd have to add DECREF for each exit, with a high risk of missing one and getting a hard-to-debug memory leak.

Comment: Is there any nonobvious way this borrowed reference can have it's reference count drop to zero? E.g. in your example, I could just follow the code and look for anyone accessing PyDict_DeleteItem, and then know that I should do a Py_INCREF. No other code from a thread or anywhere else is going to be able to run unless I've released the GIL, right?

Comment: In your opinion, would you tend toward the overuse of Py_INCREF/Py_DECREF for using borrowed references like this, or would you always take it case by case?

Comment: Yes, e.g. the delitem can be hidden in any Python code, including in the finalizer of a completely different object. But if you can truly see all details of "long code" then yes, you're safe (there's the minor issue that if it's truly long, someone maintaining it may overlook the borrowed reference and make a change that breaks the assumption). I just checked the largest extension library that I maintain (https://bitbucket.org/wlav/cpycppyy/) and it's by and large case-by-case. E.g. it's common there to call a generic Python callable in "long code" at which point defensive INCREFs are added.